# What's the minimum disk space requirement for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, system-requirements

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) suggests that 1 GB is sufficient, but when I tried installing it on a VM with a 1 GB virtual hard disk, I received a "Failed to partition the selected disk" error indicating that the disk was too small. Increasing the disk to 5 GB solved this.

How much space is required for a successful install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its depends on the Ubuntu release, 1GB is ok for 12.04 but not 14.04 with all tasks installed.

For 14.04, The official recommendation is 1.75 GB.

Sources:

- [Ubuntu 14.04 Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html#system-requirements)
- [Ubuntu 12.04 Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html#system-requirements)